# Scala remote actors won't communicate, why?

Tags: scala, actor

I'm trying to connect two remote actors on localhost (firewall disabled), but no message is coming through. I created some simple code that conveys my problem:

actor 1:

```
package test

import scala.actors._
import scala.actors.Actor._
import scala.actors.remote._
import scala.actors.remote.RemoteActor._

object Actor1 {
  RemoteActor.classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader()
}

class Actor1 extends Actor {

  def act {
    alive(9000)
    register('actor1, self)

    println("Actor1 running")
    while (true) {
      react {
        case s: String => {
          println("received1: " + s)
          sender ! "Server reply"
        }

        case _ => println("Received wierdness;)")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

actor 2:

```
package test

import scala.actors._
import scala.actors.Actor._
import scala.actors.remote._
import scala.actors.remote.RemoteActor._

object Actor2 {
  RemoteActor.classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader()
}

class Actor2 extends Actor {

  val actor1 = select(Node("127.0.0.1", 9000), 'actor1)

  def act {
    println("Sending message to actor1(" + actor1 + ")")
    actor1 ! "Message to server"

    println("Actor2 running")
    while (true) {
      react {
        case s: String => println("received2: " + s)
        case _ => println("Received wierdness;)")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the main class:

package test

```
object Test {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a1 = new Actor1()
    val a2 = new Actor2()

    println("Starting actors")
    a1.start
    a2.start
  }

}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Try Akka actors. Scala actors have been deprecated.

Comment: Thanks ;) Will surely try Akka, but still, the above code sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, I wonder why;) Anyway, thanks:)